# HSTS headers for Django + Nginx projects - should the headers be set by Django SecurityMiddleware or Nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, hsts

HSTS = HTTP Strict Transport Security

From the [Django Docs on HSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/middleware/#http-strict-transport-security)

> For sites that should only be accessed over HTTPS, you can instruct modern browsers to refuse to connect to your domain name via an insecure connection (for a given period of time) by setting the “Strict-Transport-Security” header. This reduces your exposure to some SSL-stripping man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks.
>
> SecurityMiddleware will set this header for you on all HTTPS responses if you set the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS setting to a non-zero integer value.

However this header can also be set by Nginx in the conf file, by adding a line:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;";
```

So the question is, should we configure Nginx to set this header or Django SecurityMiddleware, by adding the HSTS settings in the project settings file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's entirely up to you. If you run multiple sites it might be easier to set a global value in your webserver settings. However, if you set it in Django it will be easier to move your application to a new webserver.